# What's the sense of some interfaces and of interfaces in general?

Tags: c#, interface, idisposable

I was looking at some interface implementations as I couldn't use the 'using' keyword to be sure to dispose properly a FileInfo object in C#, but compiler gave me this error:

> 'System.IO.FileInfo': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'

So, I start documenting about implementations of these particular interfaces.

I ended up seeing that all reduces to typing :IDisposable next to the class name and add a Dispose() method myself, and that's how you make an IDisposable.

First question:

What's the sense of this? Shouldn't the framework creators make those items -disposable/nullable/whatever common use interface you want- without having us to worry about it?

It's 2 years that I work as a programmer but many years that I do as a hobby and I never understood why interface are useful or what is the purpose of them. They actually seem pretty useless to me.

From what I understood their only purpose is to serve as a "contract", which is a definition I never fully understood. People like nto say contrat while they could say "It simply means that you must reimplement all the methods of the class you inherit from, even if you make them empty", instead of that awkward "contract" definition.

Anyway, why is that? Why do I need compiler to tell me that I need to implement those methods? I guess I'll never get that.

Usually I grasped concept from studying or apllying them while coding, but I swear I never found or seen for me nor my coworkers, a situation where an interface was useful, needed, a good choiche or something convenient...

I guess I'll end up never using them even if I see people do use them a lot... Why?

Comment: Well, isn't it a bit obvious that an interface is useful just from the *using* keyword?  You can pass *any* kind of object to it.  Including ones that Microsoft never envisioned, like the classes you created.  As long as it implements IDisposable.  Much the same for the *for each* keyword, it can enumerate *any* collection object, not just ones created from a .NET Framework class, all it takes is implementing IEnumerable.

Comment: Uhm, in all that confusing stuff, maybe @HansPassant gave me a bit of light...
Anyway, I don't like it... You have to know all the interfaces to say someone, hey in my function you need an IDisposable, an IEnumerable. Creating interfaces on your own would mean that everyone that uses it should know about what methods it has...

Wouldn't be better if you implement the needed methods to handle something before needing someone to implement it into an interface??

Sorry if I sound stupid, I'm not experienced enough maybe

Comment: @user2235691: You *cannot* implement the needed methods because every implementor of an interface may implement its methods in a different way. An `IEnumerable` that returns the contents of a list is implemented in a different way than an `IEnumerable` that returns the contents received from a database server. The only part that is the same is the set of methods used to iterate over the items in the list/database result set - in other words, the public *interface*.

Answer (score 1):

C#, as with many other languages, doesn't support multiple inheritance. See [the Diamond Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem) for example.

In any case, interfaces are C#'s way to approach multiple inheritance by avoiding some of the problems that go with it. If `Class A` had a method called `Foo()` and `Class B` also had a method called `Foo()` how could you possibly resolve which one to call when you derive from both? Interfaces by specifying **what** and object can do, but not **how** it does it.

Consider `IList<T>` -- the generic form of a collection that represents an expansible list. It has methods such as `Add`, `Remove`, and `Clear`. If someone uses your class, they *shouldn't* need to worry about your implementation details, only that it works. Thus, under the hood you can have a `List<int>` or a `LinkedList<int>` and it will still function the same to your clients, *because you exposed only the interace -- the base contract -- for them to use*.

Answer (score 0):

You will use interfaces, undoubtedly.  In fact, if you were writing a `using` statement then you were already using one.

The point of a `using` statement is to create an object and ensure that it is exposed at the end of the block.  In order to be able to dispose the object, it must have a `Dispose` method.  That's where the `IDisposable` interface comes in.

The `IDisposable` interface defines the `Dispose` method.  Any class that implements `IDisposable` signs a contract to implement that `Dispose` method.  The `using` statement requires that an object have a `Dispose` method in order to be able to dispose it at the end of the block and the way that it knows that that method exists is the fact that the object you're using implements `IDisposable`.

This sort of thing is seen all over.  When you write a `foreach` loop, the object that you loop over must implement `IEnumerable`.  Under the hood, the `foreach` loop uses the functionality defined by that interface to enumerate the specified list.

Similarly, in order to bind a WinForms control like a `ComboBox`, `ListBox` or `DataGridView` to a list of data, that list must implement the `IList` interface because the underlying data-binding mechanism uses the functionality defined by that interface.

That's basically what interfaces do: they guarantee that a specific set of functionality will be available.  They make no promises about how that functionality will be implemented or what other functionality may or may not also be provided.

Think about how interfaces work elsewhere.  You use a computer so you are presumably familiar in a general sense with the USB interface.  In order to be USB compliant, a device must provide a specific set of functionality.  How it does that and what else it does is irrelevant to the USB port on the computer though.  As long as it has an appropriate USB plug that can successfully send and receive the appropriate messages then it will work.

Think of your `using` statement as an `IDisposable` port.  It doesn't matter what your object does when it's `Dispose` method is called or what other properties and methods it has, as long as it has a method named "Dispose" that has no parameters and doesn;t return anything, it can implement `IDisosable` and be accepted by the `using` statement.

Comment: ugh.. so it's all about making  an object usable by something else?

Seems pretty error prone to me, if you implement an object you didn't create on your own in an interface I guess you could end up screwing what's under the hood at some point...

Anyway thanks for the clear explanation, I liked it

Comment: @user2235691: How can you "implement an object you didn't create on your own"?

Comment: @user2235691, suffice it to say that interfaces are very useful and make life easier in C# development.  Interfaces are not inherently error-prone.  If you write bad code then you write bad code and anyone can mess up anything if they try hard enough.  You clearly don't grasp the concept as yet.  If you're up to development then you will at some point in future and it may be that a light bulb just comes on.  If you never really grasp the usefulness of interfaces then that's a sign that you're not really up to it as a developer.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning `IDisposable` in particular: First of all, being *disposable* is something very different from being *nullable*.

- Variables of every reference type are automatically nullable, which means that you can set them to `null`. You do *not* need to implement `IDisposable` for that.
- When you implement the `IDisposable` interface, you do so to free resources that the runtime cannot automatically free, or that should simply not be subject to (somewhat non-deterministic) garbage collection.
  For example, you might write a class whose instances open a file and write to it - when an instance of your class is not needed any more, the file should be closed. It should be closed then and there (because something else may want to access the file as of that moment), not "at some point after the class is not needed any more, at the latest when the process is terminated". Therefore, you should declare your own class to implement `IDisposable` (so users of your class know `Dispose` needs to be called, and also so they can use your class in a `using` block) and implement the `Dispose` method in a way that closes the file.

Now, as you said, interfaces in general serve as a "contract" - a guarantee for callers that your class implements a specific set of members. Thus, the simple answer to your question

> Why do I need compiler to tell me that I need to implement those methods?

is "So they can be called."

Consider the following example - first, an interface, and two classes implementing it, are declared:

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    bool DoSomething();

    int SomeValue { get; }
}

public class Example1 : ISomeInterface
{
    public bool DoSomething()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public int SomeValue {
        get {
            return 42;
        }
    }
}

public class Example2 : ISomeInterface
{
    public bool DoSomething()
    {
        return DateTime.IsLeapYear(DateTime.Now.Year);
    }

    public int SomeValue {
        get {
            return DateTime.Now.Year;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, let's add a class with a method that returns an implementation of `ISomeInterface`:

```
public class SomeMasterClass
{
    public static ISomeInterface CreateObject()
    {
        if (DateTime.Now.Year % 3 == 0) {
            return new Example1();
        } else {
            return new Example2();
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on internal conditions, either an instance of `Example1` or an instance of `Example2` is returned. When invoking the method, you do not know which class will actually be instantiated, and you do not need to know - **because both implement the interface** whose members you are going to use:

```
ISomeInterface myObject = SomeMasterClass.CreateObject();
Console.WriteLine(myObject.DoSomething());
Console.WriteLine(myObject.SomeValue);
```

Without the interface, the return value of `SomeMasterClass.CreateObject()` would have to be typed as [`System.Object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (because that is the most specialized common ancestor of `Example1` and `Example2`. However, as both classes implement the `ISomeInterface` interface, and thus **fulfil the contract** imposed by that interface, you can rely on their providing of implementations for the `DoSomething` method and the `SomeValue` property.

Comment: Not clear for me. Sorry but this got me more confused.
Also, I've never seen such a syntax public static ISomeInterface CreateObject() so I don't even know what you're talking about

Comment: @user2235691: If you could be more specific than "this got me more confused" about what in particular is unclear (at what sentence, what word, am I losing you?), I could maybe improve my description. In any case, `public static X Y()` declares a public static method of name `Y` that returns a value of type `X`. `public` is the [access modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) and [`static` means that the method can be called without an instance of its class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx). Please read up on those topics, then re-read this answer.